# Stored procedure execution through the role

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I ran the below script but my user still can not execute any stored procedures. So, I am wondering what is blocking my user?

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

CREATE ROLE [DB_Sproc]
GO

USE [MyDb]
GO

ALTER ROLE [DB_Sproc] ADD MEMBER [MYUser]
GO

use [MYDB]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA ::dbo TO [DB_Sproc]
GRANT EXECUTE  TO [DB_Sproc]
```

Comment: What error do you get? "The execute permission was denied..." or smth else?

Comment: Yes, The execution for the user is denied because of permission!

Comment: That means that there is an explicit deny. Is you user a domain user (is corresponding login a Windows account or SQL Server login) ?

Comment: User is a SQL user not a domain one.

Comment: This means or your user has an explicit deny, or he is a member of another role that has a deny. Please exec `exec as user = 'MYUser'; select * from sys.user_token` and tell me what roles he is member of?

Comment: ...If you find that your user is the member of public and DB_Sproc only, it's your PUBLIC that has DENY EXECUTE

Comment: Thank you I will check them.